# Moving rows to another google spreadsheet based on a condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to know if its possible to move automatically rows to another Google spreadsheet based on a condition in editing (onEdit) the specific column entry that can be text, date, null or specific number.

I tried many times without being able to solve this puzzle.

Source (shared):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Of4NUdvcxvCUWNSwpbkC4X8nqHpBetHCvyyiGqUPaJk/edit?usp=sharing

Destination (scripts) (shared):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J7ChXoodQNg47LOrnp_GF-KLR1jKHxdDGmfAErVTP_U/edit?usp=sharing

Any help is appreciated. vagner

Comment: After editing a sheet to trigger the function, or running a function directly from the code editor, look in the VIEW, EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT log to see if there are any errors.

Comment: If you have made some changes that you want to include, edit this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting an error on line 10 of your code:

[image: get Sheet by Name]

This is what your current code looks like:

```
function onEdit(){
  Logger.log("it ran!");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Of4NUdvcxvCUWNSwpbkC4X8nqHpBetHCvyyiGqUPaJk").getActiveSheet();
  var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J7ChXoodQNg47LOrnp_GF-KLR1jKHxdDGmfAErVTP_U").getActiveSheet();

  Logger.log("ss: " + ss);
  Logger.log("ssd: " + ssd);

  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var sheet2 = ssd.getSheetByName('Destination');

  Logger.log("sheet1: " + sheet1);
  Logger.log("sheet2: " + sheet2);
```

There is a problem with these two lines:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Of4NUdvcxvCUWNSwpbkC4X8nqHpBetHCvyyiGqUPaJk").getActiveSheet();
  var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J7ChXoodQNg47LOrnp_GF-KLR1jKHxdDGmfAErVTP_U").getActiveSheet();
```

You should remove `.getActiveSheet()`.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Of4NUdvcxvCUWNSwpbkC4X8nqHpBetHCvyyiGqUPaJk");
var ssd = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1J7ChXoodQNg47LOrnp_GF-KLR1jKHxdDGmfAErVTP_U");
```

That error was not showing up until I ran the code from inside of the code editor.  And I needed to authorize some things for it to run for the first time.

I ran it in Debug mode.

When you chain the `.getActiveSheet()` method on the end, it returns the SHEET class, NOT the SPREADSHEET class.  There are hierarchies of classes.  The SHEET class is a lower level under the SPREADSHEET class.  So, you were trying to use a method for the SPREADSHEET class, on a variable that contained a SHEET return type.

Comment: onEdit didn't work properly. I wished I could see on the Destination spreadsheet sorted by date (formatted dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm) in the column 16. I'm really impressed with your astonishing work!!

Comment: I didn't go through all the code, and check everything.  I just stopped at the first problem I found.  To debug the problem, it's a process of elimination.  Did the changes I made show up in your spreadsheet?  Did you check the VIEW, LOG to see what the `Logger.log();` statements printed?

Comment: I haven't seen any statement printed (log(data)Writes the string to the logging console.), but, the values were sent to destination correctly. I'm paying attention to the details of what you are saying.. thank you.